# ejs-lineargauge majorticks and minorticks middle

Tags: css, angular, ejs

I want to have majorTicks and minorTicks aligned in the middle of the axis , I have tried a lot and googled it but no ssolution found,
This is a snippet of code

```
 majorTicks: {
  height: 12,
  interval: 1,
  width: 2,
  distanceFromScale: {x: 7, y: 0}
```

Check also the screen shot in the image to understand better what I need.
Thanks in advance
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb2Pt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after searching;
Whether it is for majorTicks , minorTicks or pointers , the attribute needed is position:'Cross'
so the code will be :

```
majorTicks: {
  height: 12,
  interval: 1,
  width: 2,
  distanceFromScale: {x: 7, y: 0},
  **position:'Cross'**
```